# SQL Character Issue When Run Through The Release Process

Tags: sql, msbuild, release, special-characters

I'm using MSBuild to release my .net code and update the database. I'm having an issue with certain characters. The following scripts work fine when run in the SQL management studio. However when they are run a part of the release process the first two lines set the symbols to question marks and the second pair of update scripts add a black diamond with a question mark.

```
update dbo.Currency set symbol = '£' where id = 1
update dbo.Currency set symbol = '€' where id = 2

update dbo.Currency set symbol = N'£' where id = 1
update dbo.Currency set symbol = N'€' where id = 2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Luke

Answer (score 0):

Your script files need to be in unicode or at least ANSI to preserve the characters set.